# localhost didn’t send any data ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, node.js

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE was working on my nodejs works but got stuck here

```
const http = require("https");

const server = http.createServer();
server.on("request", (req, res) => {
    var fs = require("fs");
    fs.readFile("input.txt", (err, data) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        res.end(data);
    });
});

server.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

Ask if want more information on this.
Was running it via

nodemon index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a request listener in the `createServer` function like:

```js
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    const fs = require("fs");
    fs.readFile("input.txt", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end(`File Read Error: ${err.message}`);
        }      
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}
const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I appreciate for your help, and it did worked. Can you explain a little more on your part?

Comment: You can find the details for node.js http server [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTP-server/) If you want to expand your http server you can use the `express` framework [here](https://afteracademy.com/blog/getting-started-with-expressjs) a getting startet example to follow :)

Comment: You can find the details for node.js http server [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTP-server/) If you want to expand your http server you can use the `express` framework [here](https://afteracademy.com/blog/getting-started-with-expressjs) a getting startet example to follow :)